# Firebase: Error decoding custom claims on client after Facebook login

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have the logic shown in "[Access custom claims on the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client)" in my web app, with the same implementation of `b64DecodeUnicode` as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).

After a Google or Email login the custom claims in an ID Token can be base64 decoded, and I can log to the console the resulting json.

`{"iss":"https://securetoken.google.com/my-app","name":"Joe Bloggs","picture":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg","aud": ... etc.`

However after a Facebook login I see the error:

`Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

Indeed when I manually take the 2nd part of the ID token and try to base64 decode it, it appears to be corrupted after the `?` in the `picture` value (url).

The decoded string contains something like:

`https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/\YLLMML͌L`

But would expect the string to contain:

`https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=`

At the time of writing I'm using the latest firebase ([4.12.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/releases/tag/firebase%404.12.1)) and firebaseui ([2.7.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/releases/tag/v2.7.0)) packages.

Is this a bug in Firebase, i.e. has the ID Token been incorrectly encoded?  Or is my approach to decoding it at fault?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a Firebase documentation issue.  When using [jwt-decode](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) to decode the token things work fine.  Digging into the jwt-decode [source code, the line](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/8ab1bd5dbd24e68da8b47222fb92a46bba0578c9/lib/base64_url_decode.js#L14):

`var output = str.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");`

is what fixes things in this case (the token in question has an '_').